# Eclipse IDE: The package com.google.zxing is not accessible, despite importing the right libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to implement a QR code generator and scanner in a desktop application written in Java from the Eclipse IDE. I am following this tutorial: [Java code to Generate QR Code and Read QR Code using Camera https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBibVwgi09g&t=193s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBibVwgi09g&t=193s)

Here is my code for generating the QR code:

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;

public class QRGenerator {
    
    public void generateQRcode(String data, String path, String charset, Map map, int h, int w) throws WriterException, IOException {
        BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(new String(data.getBytes(charset), charset), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, w, h);
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(path));
    } 
    
}
```

I already imported the Jar Libraries into Eclipse using this other tutorial: [How to Import or Add Jar Libraries in Eclipse https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWTzZ4sNAFw] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWTzZ4sNAFw)

This is what my project folder looks like. The project name is Splogurt_OOP_MiniProject.
[Jar files are imported into the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwho6.png)

The code should have no errors, but there are sqwiggly red lines under text like `com.google.zxing`, `com.google.zxing.client.j2se`, `com.google.zxing.common` and a few other parts of the code.

The errors say things like "The package from com.google.zxing is not accessible."

[Screenshot of my QR generator code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYhjR.png)

I already deleted and re-made my module-info.java file to try and fix this:

```
module Splogurt_OOP_MiniProject {
    exports application;

    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javase;
    
    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
    
    requires Webcam;
}
```

How do I solve these errors?

Comment: You did not import the right libraries. `com.google` is not from `javafx`. It's from some google library, hence why the package name includes `google`.

Comment: So I cannot use the library in my JavaFX project... I'm going to have to find another way to implement the QR code scanner and generator.

Comment: Of course you can. just add the dependency to the project's dependency list.

Comment: How do I "add the dependency" to the project's dependency list? I am using a JavaFXML in an Eclipse IDE. I already added the Jar files to the project's Java Build Path.

Comment: In your gradle or maven build description file. Adding the jars to the build path _will_ get rid of those errors, so double check that you really did that.